# Why the audio plays sometimes and sometimes not within the same browser?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser, hosting

I have the following code and I am not sure what's wrong. Is there any problem with the remote  host on which we have the audio files? In Chrome, sometimes it plays and sometimes it doesn't play and when it doesn't play, it doesn't say that my browser doesn't support the audio format.

```
<audio controls id="audio" style="display:none">
    <source src="http://langcomplab.net/Honey_Gatherers_Master.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser doesn't support this audio format.
</audio>
<button id="button">Play</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // run on page load
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    var onClick = function() {
        audio.play(); // audio will load and then play
    };

    button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MfU7h/

UPDATE: The is really weird. In the source section I add

```
</html> tag for a block in Qualtrics but when I source my code using rich context editor the tags fade away. Any solution to this? 
<html>
<body onload='Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload'>
<p>The next two stories will be the two stories presented auditorily. Please press the &ldquo;Play Story&rdquo; button now to hear an example auditory story. Be sure to adjust the volume of the device on which you are listening so that you can hear the auditory story clearly.</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div>
<audio controls="" id="audio1" style="display:none"><source src="http://langcomplab.net/Test_take2.mp3" style="width:50%" type="audio/mpeg" />Your browser doesn&#39;t support this audio format.</audio>
</div>

<div><button name="play" onclick="disabled=true" style="height:25px; width:200px" type="button">Play Story</button>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

P.S.: Am I using the right function in `onload` section?

Comment: I am refreshing it but doesn't seem to run into your problem on chrome

Comment: I really don't know what's the source of problem. It wasn't working 1 hour ago for me and now it is working. I don't know how to regenerate the problem.

Comment: Your button doesn't work on my iPad (the audio file seems to load very slowly and it gets stuck at 0:00) Ps: `display:none` doesn't work on iOS

Comment: Derek we haven't yet designed for mobile systems. We are just focusing for desktop. However thank you so much for the comment. I will keep that in mind. P.S.: Is there any replacement for display:none in iPad?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you need to execute your code after page load. E.g. (UPDATED)

```
<body onload='loadAudio'>

<audio controls id="audio" style="display:none">
    <source src="http://langcomplab.net/Honey_Gatherers_Master.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser doesn't support this audio format.
</audio>
<button id="button">Play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadAudio() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    var onClick = function() {
        audio.play(); // audio will load and then play
    };

    button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}
</script>
</body>
```

I think the reason your code works sometimes and not others is because currently it is dependent on how fast the DOM loads - the javascript can execute before the audio tag has been fully loaded into the page.

Comment: Not only dependant on how fast the DOM loads, but how fast the sound effect loads. If the MP3 has loaded by the time play() is called, it can play, but you can't play a sound effect that hasn't loaded yet. However your solution works. Wait until the sound effect has loaded before playing it

Comment: @mdsomerfield can you please take a look at the updated question? I tried your solution in Qualtrics (where I am creating the survey) but it didn't work.

Comment: @Mona Jalal I've updated the example to clarify what I meant. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Qualtrics so I can't provide much guidance with that.

Comment: @tomysshadow that's not entirely accurate, at least not for latest Firefox and Chrome builds - as long as the DOM element is loaded then play() will queue the audio so that it will start as soon as it is downloaded. If it is already downloaded, it will play immediately, if not, it will start once the download has been complete.